# javascript to build category tree from flat json array (data structure )

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to use javascript to convert given flat JSON array dynamically to build category tree.
But I'm not sure how I can solve this problem in optimal way so the solution can be scalable. The Category tree needs to derived from "name" property separated by "/".
Here is my initial try.

```
let data = [{"name":"file1.txt"},{"name":"folderA/file2.txt"},{"name":"folderA/folderB/file3.txt"},{"name":"file4.txt"}];
let tree = [];
function buildTree(data){
    data.forEach(obj => {
    let fileNameArr = obj.name.split("/");
    if(fileNameArr.length > 1){
     // Not sure
      }
    } else {
        let node = obj;
        node.type = "file";
        tree.push(node)
    }
  })
}

console.log(buildTree(data));
```

Expected output is:

```
[{"name":"file1.txt",
  "type":"file"
  },
 {
  "name":"folderA",
  "type":"Folder",
  "children":[
    {"name":"file2.txt",
     "type":"file"
    },
    {"name":"folderB",
     "type":"folder",
     "children":[{"name":"file3.txt","type":"file"}]
    }]
  },
 {"name":"file4.txt",
   "type":"file"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, I find it easier to do two transformations.  The first would convert the above to this structure:

```json
{
    "file1.txt": {
        "name": "file1.txt",
        "type": "file",
        "children": {}
    },
    "folderA": {
        "name": "folderA",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": {
            "file2.txt": {
                "name": "file2.txt",
                "type": "file",
                "children": {}
            },
            "folderB": {
                "name": "folderB",
                "type": "folder",
                "children": {
                    "file3.txt": {
                        "name": "file3.txt",
                        "type": "file",
                        "children": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "file4.txt": {
        "name": "file4.txt",
        "type": "file",
        "children": {}
    }
}
```

and the second would flatten this down to an array, doing the same recursively with the children.  Here is my approach:

```js
// utility function
const call = (fn, ...args) => 
  fn (...args)

// main functions
const nest = (files) => files .reduce ((tree, file) => {
  file .name .split ('/') .reduce ((node, name, i, a) => {
    return (node [name] || (node[name] = {
      name, 
      type: i == a.length - 1 ? 'file' : 'folder', 
      children: {}
    })).children
  }, tree)
  return tree 
}, {})

const flattenChildren = (tree) =>
  Object .values (tree)
    .map (({children, ...rest}) => call (
      (kids) => ({
        ... rest, 
        ... (kids.length ? {children: kids} : {})
      }),
      children ? flattenChildren (children) : []
    ))


// public function
const makeTree = (files) =>
  flattenChildren (nest (files))


// sample input
const input = [{name: 'file1.txt'}, {name: 'folderA/file2.txt'}, {name: 'folderA/folderB/file3.txt'}, {name: 'file4.txt'}]


// demo
console .log (makeTree (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

- **`call`** is a trivial helper function that just makes it easier to do expression-based programming and avoid unnecessary assignments.  It takes any number of arguments, with the first one a function, and calls the function with the remaining ones.
- **`nest`** turns your input into the intermediate structure I described.
- **`flattenChildren`** turns this intermediate format into your final one.
- **`makeTree`** is the public function which combines the above.

There is a slightly odd mix of styles here.  Usually if I use recursive techniques in one key function in a solution, I do so for all them.  But here, even though `flattenChildren` is recursive, the first version of `nest` that I thought of uses nested `.reduce` calls.  I'm sure I could change that, but I'm not ready to spend more time on this now.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and build a nested folder strruture by having a look to the avtual level and find the wanted name. If not found add a new object and return the children array for pushing the file.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "file1.txt" }, { name: "folderA/file2.txt" }, { name: "folderA/folderB/file3.txt" }, { name: "file4.txt" }],
    tree = data.reduce((r, { name }) => {
        const
            folders = name.split('/'),
            file = folders.pop();

        folders
            .reduce((level, name) => {
                let temp = level.find(q => q.name === name);
                if (!temp) level.push(temp = { name, type: 'folder', children: [] });
                return temp.children;
            }, r)
            .push({ name: file, type: 'file' });

        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A version without using `find`, but an object with the result inside.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "file1.txt" }, { name: "folderA/file2.txt" }, { name: "folderA/folderB/file3.txt" }, { name: "file4.txt" }],
    tree = data.reduce((_, { name }) => {
        const
            folders = name.split('/'),
            file = folders.pop();

        folders
            .reduce((level, name) => {
                if (!level[name]) {
                    level[name] = { _: [] };
                    level._.push({ name, type: 'folder', children: level[name]._ });
                }
                return level[name];
            }, { _ })
            ._
            .push({ name: file, type: 'file' });
        return _;
    }, []);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You reduce the entire array to a Map initialize with `root` (the base array). Whenever you create a folder, you also add it to the Map using it's path as key, while also adding it to the current folder.

After getting/adding the last folder (stored in `current`), add the file to current.

The entire tree is stored in the `root` key of the Map.

```js
const data = [{ name: "file1.txt" }, { name: "folderA/file2.txt" }, { name: "folderA/folderB/file3.txt" }, { name: "file4.txt" }];

const createFile = name => ({ name, type: 'file' });
const createFolder = name => ({ name, type: 'folder', children: [] });

const tree = data.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
  const path = name.split('/'); // get the path
  
  const file = createFile(path.pop()); // create the file
  
  let current = acc.get('root'); // init current at the root
  
  // iterate current to get to the last folder, while creating missing levels
  path.forEach((folderName, i) => {
    const key = path.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'); // create the key for the current folder
    
    if(!acc.has(key)) { // if folder not part of the Map, create it
      const folder = createFolder(folderName);
      acc.set(key, folder); // add the folder to the Map
      (current.children || current).push(folder) // add folder to current children / root
    }
  
    current = acc.get(key); // move current to the folder
  });
  
  (current.children || current).push(file) // add file to current children / root

  return acc;
}, new Map([['root', []]])) // init the the Map with a root folder
.get('root'); // get the tree from the root

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

We can slightly optimize this by iterating the `path` array backwards using a `while` loop, and stop the iteration when a folder already exists, or we're at the root.

```js
const data = [{ name: "file1.txt" }, { name: "folderA/file2.txt" }, { name: "folderA/folderB/file3.txt" }, { name: "file4.txt" }];

const createFile = name => ({ name, type: 'file' });
const createFolder = (name, child) => ({ name, type: 'folder', children: [child] });

const tree = data.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
  const path = name.split('/'); // get the path
  
  let branch = createFile(path.pop()); // create the file

  while(path.length && !acc.get(path.join('/'))) { // iterate while path not empty, and folder doesn't exist
    branch = createFolder(path[path.length - 1], branch); // create the folder and add the previous item to the children
    
    acc.set(path.join('/'), branch); // add to the Map
    
    path.pop(); // remove the last folder from the path
  };
  
  acc.get(path.length ? path.join('/') : 'root').children.push(branch); // add to pre-existing folder or to the root

  return acc;
}, new Map([['root', { children: [] }]])) // init the the Map with a root folder
.get('root').children; // get the tree from the root

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```